# onSubmit doesn't work on the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm making a page that retrieves coordinates from a database and shows them as markers on google maps. I have a submit button that lets you delete a selected marker. What I'm trying to do is add a warning before deleting, but it unfortunately doesn't work. I've tried with onSubmit and with onClick (which is probably wrong anyway). I've been searching for hours but nothing seems to work. I don't think the rest of the code is important, but I'll post it if needed. Any ideas? Here's the code of the form:

```
echo '<form align="center" onSubmit="return confirm("Are you sure?")" class = "delete" id="delete_form" name = "marker_list2" action="delete_marker.php" method="post">';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="edit">';
        echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Why are you using `onSubmit`? Stop using such inline-elements, and put these handlers in an external js-file, which reacts on elements being clicked on the page.

Comment: Inline JS is totally appropriate for small snippets like this, IMO... no need to write more code or spread it out across multiple files, reducing at-a-glance readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've got conflicting double-quotes. Try replacing

```
onSubmit="return confirm("Are you sure?")"
```

with

```
onSubmit="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"
```

Make sure to escape the single quotes, because it is inside your PHP `echo '...'`

Comment: Oops, didn't see that from your question...maybe you want to include the whole echo statement? (Also, I just suggested adding the PHP tag to the question.)